Microsoft Entra ID External Authentication Method
I need to implement an external authentication method for Microsoft Entra ID using PHP, but I haven't found much documentation on it.
According to the documentation, to add an External Authentication Method (EAM), we need to provide:
Client ID
Discovery Endpoint
App ID

Here are the relevant links:
Managing External Authentication Methods
Concept of External Authentication Method Providers

My question is: Do we need to generate the discovery endpoint on the PHP authorization server itself, or is this the URL we obtained while creating the application in Entra: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?
registered the app in portal.azure.com for client id and secret

Discovery endpoint is the OpenID well-known endpoint which is always provided by Microsoft Entra ID and Microsoft Entra External ID.
You do not have to generate it anywhere.
For the standard Microsoft Entra ID tenant it is in this format:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT-ID/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
For the Microsoft Entra External ID tenant (for customers) it is in this format:
https://TENANT-NAME.ciamlogin.com/TENANT-NAME.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
You have to provide Client ID and above discovery endpoint to your application so it can successfully load OpenID Connect configuration (for in stance to discover authorization and token endpoints).
